# The NavigationStack in SwiftUI doesn't seem to animate from a ForEach with a custom label?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, navigationview

I'm working with the new NavigationStack API for my SwiftUI project in lieu of NavigationView (Xcode 14, beta 2), as NavigationView is being deprecated. Prior to trying NavigationStack, the navigationLinks would animate as they transitioned between views. As well, the old navigationView API would allow the user to go backwards, one view at a time.  So with the new Navigation*Stack*, and using a standard destination and label argument (without a custom label), the views do not animate, and they also pop to root. Neither of these are desirable. I need to use a label as the row-cell view in my forEach, as this view contains pertinent information.

I have tried the new NavigationStack approach which consists of a title and value argument. It also consists of a navigationDestination modifier. When I go this route, the views animate at transition, and the user can go back one view at a time. This is great, however, I can't seem to get a label to work as needed.

When I try and use the new navStack with a value, and its associated navigationDestination, I get an error on my VStack link  right after the body is called.

That error reads:
*"Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'CGFloat?' that does not accept a closure"'*

My code for this view below:

EDITED TO INCLUDE:
** The View containing the NavStack**

```
struct MainTabView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            
            VStack {
                SearchBarView()
                
                QuickAddButtonsView()
                
                TabView{
                    
                    StatisticsView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "list.number")
                            Text("Statistics")
                        }
                        .tag(1)                    
                    AccountsListDatabaseView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "building.fill")
                            Text("Accounts")
                        }
                        .tag(2)                    
                }
            }
        }         
    }
}
```

**AccountListDataBaseView**

```
import SwiftUI


struct AccountsListDatabaseView: View {
    
    @State private var showAlert = false    
    @State private var indexSetToDelete: IndexSet?
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc    
    @EnvironmentObject var searchClass: SearchClass
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\AccountCoreData.accountName)]) var accountFetch: FetchedResults<AccountCoreData>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            // presents total number of accounts
            AccountCounterForList()
            
            List{
                 ForEach(accountFetch) { account in     
                         
// the fix was to add the value as an argument to the navLink api. This seems to work.
                                                NavigationLink(value: account) {
                            AccountDataCellRowView(accountCoreData: account)
                        }   
 
                     NavigationLink(account.wrappedAccountName, value: account) 
                        }                    
                }
                
                //delete from extension below
                .onDelete { (indexSet) in
                    self.showAlert = true
                    self.indexSetToDelete = indexSet
                }
                // nav for forEach
                .navigationDestination(for: AccountCoreData.self) { account in
                    MainAccountView(accountCoreData: account)
                }
                // bg color fix
                .listRowBackground(Color.rangerGreySuperLight)                
            }
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onChanged ({ _ in
                    UIApplication.shared.dismissKeyboard()
                }))            
            //presents option to delete / cancel
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                Alert(
                    title: Text("Delete This Account?"),
                    message: Text("This account, its contacts, notes, and quotes, will be permanently deleted."),
                    primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                        self.deleteValue(index: self.indexSetToDelete!)
                    },
                    secondaryButton: .cancel())
            }            
        }
        .listStyle(.inset)
    }
}


// delete button used for swiping with alert
extension AccountsListDatabaseView{    
    func deleteValue(index: IndexSet) {
        deleteAccount(at: index)        
        do {
            moc.perform {
                try? moc.save()
                DataController.shared.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
        try? moc.save()
    }    
    func deleteAccount(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for offset in offsets {
            let account = accountFetch[offset]
            moc.delete(account)
        }
        try? moc.save()
    }
}
```

An here is the view for the forEach row cell:

**AccountDataCellRowView**

```
Struct AccountDataCellRowView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var accountCoreData: AccountCoreData
    
    var opacityAmmount: CGFloat  = 0.3
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack  {
                
                ListRowHeaderIcon(
                    iconName: "building.fill",
                    iconColor: .rangerBlue)
                
                Text("\(accountCoreData.wrappedAccountName)")
                    .font(.system(.body, design: .rounded))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.rangerGreyDark)
                    .offset(x: -2)
                
                Spacer()
                
                // dating
                VStack {
                    
                    // date added
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Text("\(accountCoreData.accountDateAdded ?? Date(),  style: .date)")
                            .fontWeight(.thin)
                            .dateTextFormat()
                        
                    }
                 
                    if accountCoreData.accountFollowUpBool == true {
                        // date follow up
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            
                            BellIcon()
                            
                            Text("\(accountCoreData.accountDateFollowUp ?? Date(),  style: .date)")
                                .fontWeight(.thin)
                                .dateTextFormat()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            
            // quick glance at quotes
            HStack (alignment: .bottom) {
                
                HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    
                    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                        
                        Text("Quotes")
                            .font(.system(.caption, design: .rounded))
                            .fontWeight(.regular)
                            .foregroundColor(.rangerGreyDark)
                            .offset(y: 8)
                        
                        GroupBox {
                            //
                            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                
                                // won
                                HStack{
                                    Text("Won:")
                                        .font(.system(.caption, design: .rounded))
                                        .fontWeight(.thin)
                                        .foregroundColor(.rangerGreyDark)
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                    Text("\(accountCoreData.quoteSumWon  as NSNumber, formatter: CurrencyFormatter.currencyFormatNoDecimal )")
                                        .font(.system(.caption, design: .rounded))
                                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                                        .foregroundColor(.rangerGreyDark)
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                }
                                
                                // open
                                HStack{
                                    Text("Open:")
                                        .font(.system(.caption, design: .rounded))
                                        .fontWeight(.thin)
                                        .foregroundColor(.rangerGreyDark)
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                    Text("\(accountCoreData.quoteSumOpen  as NSNumber, formatter: CurrencyFormatter.currencyFormatNoDecimal )")
                                        .font(.system(.caption, design: .rounded))
                                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                                        .foregroundColor(.rangerGreyDark)
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: 120, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                        .groupBoxStyle(WhiteRangerGroupBoxStyle())
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                        CounterIcon(
                            iconName: "person.fill",
                            iconColor: accountCoreData.contactFirstNameArray.count == 0 ? .contactColor.opacity(opacityAmmount) :  .contactColor,
                            iconCount: "\(accountCoreData.contactFirstNameArray.count)")
                        
                        CounterIcon(
                            iconName: "text.quote",
                            iconColor:  accountCoreData.quoteNameArray.count == 0 ? .quoteColor.opacity(opacityAmmount) : .quoteColor,
                            iconCount: "\(accountCoreData.quoteNameArray.count)")
                        
                        CounterIcon(
                            iconName: "note.text",
                            iconColor: accountCoreData.noteDateArray.count == 0 ? .noteColor.opacity(opacityAmmount) : .noteColor,
                            iconCount: "\(accountCoreData.noteDateArray.count)")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 120, alignment: .leading)
        
    }
}
```

Please let know if there is any information I'm missing here.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: And where is actually NavigationStack itself? So many needed code... but not that under question.

Comment: The NavStack is on a TabView as the TabView contains two tabs, and two other views. I will edit my post to reflect.

Comment: @asperi edited for more info.

Comment: What gives you the idea to call the init of AccountDataCellRowView with a closure? It clearly has no such property. Did you perhaps mean to create a NavigationLink where AccountDataCellRowView is the destination?

Comment: I think you're right. I realized it had something to do with this, and not placing the value call where it should have been.  I'll update my post accordingly.  Thank you!

Comment: Do not edit the question to include the answer, this is only confusing for future readers and doesn’t follow the q&a pattern here at SO. Either post the correct code as an answer or remove the question